# Create speed up search query elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I needs to change the current code searching because it looks too slow one search takes about 15 seconds.

We are looking for the parameters

> ```
> ?uids=1,2
> ```

I have this code:

```
private NativeSearchQueryBuilder getSearchQuery(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());

        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));
        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        //access for many uids
        if (searchParams.getUids() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUids().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
            filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("uid", v)));
        });
        }
        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCategories() != null) {
            for(String category : searchParams.getCategories().split(",")){
                 Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategories().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
            filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
        });
             }
        }

        if (searchParams.getItemId() != null) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getItemId()).field("_id"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        if (searchParams.getOrderBy() != null && searchParams.getOrderDir() != null) {
            if (searchParams.getOrderDir().toLowerCase().equals("asc")) {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.ASC));
            } else {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.DESC));
            }
        }

        if (pageable != null) {
            searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
        }
        return searchQuery;
    }
```

**Searching lasts 15 sec. 16k records.**

**We are looking for the parameters**

> ```
> ?uids=1,2&title=xyz
> ```

**Searching lasts 15 sec. 800 records**

---

**We are looking for the following parameters:**

> ```
> ?uids=1,2
> ```

**I change the code to(look boolQueryBuilder):**

```
private NativeSearchQueryBuilder getSearchQuery(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());

        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));
        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        //access for many uids
        if (searchParams.getUids() != null) {
            for (String user : searchParams.getUids().split(",")) {
                boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(user).field("uid"));
            }
        }
        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCategories() != null) {
            for(String category : searchParams.getCategories().split(",")){
                 boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(category).field("cat"));
             }
        }

        if (searchParams.getItemId() != null) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getItemId()).field("_id"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        if (searchParams.getOrderBy() != null && searchParams.getOrderDir() != null) {
            if (searchParams.getOrderDir().toLowerCase().equals("asc")) {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.ASC));
            } else {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.DESC));
            }
        }

        if (pageable != null) {
            searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
        }
        return searchQuery;
    }
```

---

**Searching lasts 3s. 16k records.**

**We are looking for the following parameters:**

> ```
> ?uids=1,2&title=xyz
> ```

**Searching lasts 3s. 3 million records.**

It looks as if the query these parameters are combined using OR and returns too many results. How to change the code to find work as the creation **boolQueryBuilder**?

For any help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

The way ElasticSearch's bool query works is:

- The `must` query, well, must match the found document
- The `should` queries just boost the resulting score

If `must` matches, but none of the `should`queries do, still all results for `must` will be returned.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Depending on your actual search needs, you may want to wrap your queries for queries for `uid` and `title` in another `and`-query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-query.html

You would then have a hierarchy like this:

```
{
    "bool": {
         "must": {
             "and": [
                  "query_string": { /* for title */ },
                  "query_string": { /* for uid */ }
             ]
         },
         "should": [ /* more queries to boost documents with matching fields */ ]
    }

}
```

Generally, I'd also question the use of a `search query`-query for uid. I guess a `term` query might be more performant.